# forward reference extends over definition of value

Tags: scala

I'm learning nested functions in Scala and here is some code I'm having trouble with

```
object Main extends App {
    val fac = (x: Int) => {
        val factorial: (Int, Int) => Int = (x, accum) => if (x == 1) accum else factorial(x-1, accum*x)
        factorial(x,1)
    }

    println(fac(3))
}
```

the compiler gives this error:

> forward reference extends over definition of value factorial
>
> val factorial: (Int, Int) => Int = (x, accum) => if (x == 1) accum else factorial(x-1, accum*x)**

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should declare `factorial` using `def` and not `val`:

- Using `val` means it's a *value*, evaluated *once*, at declaration; Therefore, it's easy to see why the compiler can't *use* that definition while evaluating it
- Using `def` means it's a *method*, evaluated separately for every call, therefore supporting referencing itself within the definition (recursion)

Perhaps a less-confusing way to write this would be to declare this method as a method that expects arguments, instead of a method that returns a function which expects these arguments:

```
val fac = (x: Int) => {
  def factorial(x: Int, accum: Int): Int = if (x == 1) accum else factorial(x-1, accum*x)
  factorial(x,1)
}
```

Comment: When should I use a function over a method?

Comment: Methods can be generic, functions can't. Methods can have multiple parameter lists (or none), functions always have exactly one. Methods have names, functions don't. Methods can have repeated parameters, functions can't. Methods can have optional parameters, functions can't. Methods can have implicit parameter lists, functions can't. So, if methods can do so many things that functions cannot, why would you ever want to use a function? Well, there is one very important thing: functions are objects, methods are not. And since Scala is an OO language, you can only do things with objects. You …

Comment: … cannot pass a method as an argument, you cannot return a method, you cannot assign a method to a variable, you cannot store a method in a data structure. You can only do that with objects.

Comment: Very good and detailed explanation for when to use method and function. If a method has to be used as a function, one can use eta expression to do conversion.